# Unable to redirect to reset password link without being logged

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm new to react router and implementing a log in system, however, since i didn't build the whole app i'm not quite sure why all the Routes redirect to /#/ if the user is not logged in..

I'm using React Router and I want someone to be able to click on a link on an email that takes them to

http://localhost:3001/auth/forgot8b8dc686ee38320f7f5dd7b858e62a402cd2f0bb#/

This is how i'm referencing the link in react router

```
`  {
    path: "/forgot",
    component: loadable(() => import("./layout/forgot/forgot")),
    pure: false,
    exact: true
  },`

`<ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <IndexLayout>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/forgot' component={Forgot} />
            <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/foo/all" />} />
            {routes.map(route => (
              <Route
                path={route.path}
                component={route.component}
                key={route.path}
                exact={route.exact}
              />
            ))}
            <Route component={NotFound404} />
          </Switch>
          <ToastContainer autoClose={8000} hideProgressBar={true} />
        </IndexLayout>
      </ConnectedRouter>`
```

If i'm not logged in the above just redirects me to my home page and I cannot even see that URL being called in the console, however if i am logged in, I can see that component being rendered on my dashboard (i don't want it to be rendered inside my dashboard  I want it to be a page non logged in users can use to reset their password similar to my home page)

Essentially I want a route non logged in users can go to without it being inside my dashboard.

My forgot page with the field where users can input their new password is located in the .layout folder that is also the location of my IndexLayout

```
`import IndexLayout from "./layout";`
```

My dashboard is only supposed to get render if the user is logged in

```
`return this.props.user.authenticated && this.props.user ? (
      <Dashboard children={children} user={user} />
    ) `
```

However I don't see why this would affect what i can and can't see.

I normally use standard express and pug to build my apps and i would just do a app.get('forgot:token'(req,res,next)=>{etc}) etc..

Answer (score 3):

Given that your URL is http://localhost:3001/auth/forgot8b8dc686ee38320f7f5dd7b858e62a402cd2f0bb#/

The path pattern `/forgot` doesn't match this. Which is why you're not landing on the `Forgot` component.

You could change your URL structure to something like:

```
.../forgot/8b8dc686ee38320f7f5dd7b858e62a402cd2f0bb
```

Then you can retrieve the token using [React Router URL Params](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params) like this:

```
<Route exact path='/forgot/:token' component={Forgot} />
```

Comment: Thanks, i've changed the routes to :    `  {
    path: "/forgot/:token",
    component: loadable(() => import("./layout/forgot/forgot")),
    exact: true
  },`  and ` <Route exact path='/forgot/:token' component={Forgot} />` however, I keep experiencing the same issue where the forgot page will only load if the user logs in and gets access to the dashboard, I think this may be an authorization issue, just wish I knew where it says that you have to be authenticated to get past the main page.